# Can not find MPRemoteCommandCenter in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I have created a music application and now I wanted to add a feature to control the music from the lock screen and control center but I am getting the error, MPRemoteCommandCenter not in scope.

Here is how my code looks.

I am developing in XCode 12, but for iOS 12.4.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class SongViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
   
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
        
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
        
        setupRemoteTransportControls()
        setupNowPlaying()
        
        
    }
    
    func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
        
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

       
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            print("Play command - is playing: \(self.player.isPlaying)")
            if !self.player.isPlaying {
                self.play()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }

        // Add handler for Pause Command
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            print("Pause command - is playing: \(self.player.isPlaying)")
            if self.player.isPlaying {
                self.pause()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import the `MediaPlayer` framework

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import MediaPlayer

...
```